# Why can't I see script injected using GWT ScriptInjector?

Tags: gwt

I'm trying out using GWT's ScriptInjector for the first time, and was wondering why I can't see the injected script as a  tag anywhere in the page when I view page source. I'd expect it to show up in the page head.

I'm using a dead simple example, which works in that it displays the alert. I'm just wondering why I can't physically see it injected in the page. Also if I declare a JavaScript variable inside my script, it doesn't seem available on the global scope.

```
ScriptInjector.fromString("window.alert('testing');")
.setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW)
.inject();
```

Comment: You have just shared that is working. What is not working? Please share the code. Please have a look at my post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ScriptInjector` works by injecting your js snippet into the top level window object and, by default, remove it just after it got evaluated (if you used `fromString()`; with `fromUrl()` the element is *not* removed by default). This is why you do not see it, but it actually executes.

If you want to keep the injected script element, just use `setRemoveTag(false)` on your builder `FromString` object, i.e.:

```java
ScriptInjector.fromString("window.alert('testing');")
  .setRemoveTag(false)
  .setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW)
  .inject();
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. Although even using fromUrl(), or fromString() with .setRemoveTag(false), I still don't see the injected script element in the page source. There are a lot of things going in in this app so maybe something else is going on here. I'll try with a simpler app and see if that works.

Comment: Actually, it does work with setRemoveTag(false). Just missed it in between various other things on the page. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at below sample.

I have modified the inner HTML of a `div`. The changes are visible in Firebug but if you view the source it will be not there.

**EntryPointClass:**

```
ScriptInjector.fromString("document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML='hi';")
            .setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW).inject();
```

**HTML:**

```
<html>
 ...
    <body>
        <div id='mydiv'></div>  
    </body>
 ...
</html>
```

**Snapshot:**

[image]

**View Source:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess I'm expecting to see an actual <script> tag in the page head, which I'm not seeing (even if I use setRemoveTag(false)).

Comment: Actually was just being dumb, it does work. And also was earlier stupidly not looking in the firebug html tab.